# What is the best way to style text in the middle of an h tag or p tag?

Tags: html

I need to be able to add the class="remove" onto the text that I put in the separate div, without it moving down to a new line. I don't know what kind of tag I should use to achieve this.

```
<p class="font-weight-semibold text-3 mb-0 appear-animation" data-appear-animation="maskUp"
                        data-appear-animation-delay="200">~Scroll down to view our <strong><i>scrollable </i></strong> weekly schedule <div class="remove">and what is included
                        with membership here at Dynamic Wrestling Academy</div></p>
```

Comment: How about a `<span>`? And also, `<p>` elements can't contain `<div>` elements. Invalid HTML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can't have a div inside a p tag.  also, make the inner div inline. Or as suggested make the inner div a span

```css
.remove{
    display:inline
}
```

```html
<div class="font-weight-semibold text-3 mb-0 appear-animation" data-appear-animation="maskUp" data-appear-animation-delay="200">
  ~Scroll down to view our
  <strong><i>scrollable </i></strong> weekly schedule

  <div class="remove">and what is included with membership here at Dynamic Wrestling Academy</div>

</div>


<p class="font-weight-semibold text-3 mb-0 appear-animation" data-appear-animation="maskUp" data-appear-animation-delay="200">
  ~Scroll down to view our
  <strong><i>scrollable </i></strong> weekly schedule
  <span class="remove">and what is included with membership here at Dynamic Wrestling Academy</span>
</p>
```

Comment: Ok so you can't have a div inside of a p tag, but you can have a span inside a p tag?

Comment: Yes grasshopper, you can have a span inside a p tag